# How do I use Ring to output my post data in a request?

Tags: clojure, ring, compojure

In using clojure-ring I'm trying to do a simple test by posting data form a form and then printing it to the browser.

```
(defroutes approutes
  ;posting test
  (POST "/upload" [req]
    (str "the wonderful world of wonka presents " req)))
```

when I try posting data via curl it gives me a 200 okay status code, but it doesn't actually fill in the body of the request with the params.  Perhaps I am overlooking something fundamental about Ring.

edt:
what it does output is

```
the wonderful world of wonka presents
```

but the rest doesn't show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[compojure's destructuring](https://github.com/weavejester/compojure/wiki/Destructuring-Syntax) tries to access the *query/form parameter* `:req` in your example, not the whole request. You have two possibilities:

```
(POST "..." req ...)
```

and

```
(POST "..." [something :as req] ...)
```

Both store the request in `req`, the second variant allows you to still use destructuring , though.

Comment: thank you for the link.  i did not know that about the destructuring syntax.  actually, you are amazing.  i updated the name of the field to the "name" attribute of the input area and it works.